# Embossed color box

Tags: 3d, box, colorbox

I need to have
**embossed colorbox** in latex with text within
(like the 
`\fcolorbox{border-color}{fill-color}{text}`
) the same as the folowing picture?
[image]

Is it posible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would be surprised if variants of this didn't exist somewhere already, but here is a way do draw such things with Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{203,222,158}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{144,206,244}
\newcommand{\FFcolorbox}[2][]{\begin{tikzpicture}[FF/.cd,
    Fcol/.code={\colorlet{fcol}{##1}},Fcol=myblue,
    a/.initial=0.5ex,w/.initial=2em,h/.initial=2em,#1]
 \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/FF/##1}}% 
 \node[minimum width=\pv{w},minimum height=\pv{h},fill=fcol,
    align=center,outer sep=0pt](F){#2};
 \path[left color=fcol,right color=white,shading angle=180]
 (F.north west) -- ++ (-\pv{a},\pv{a}) -- 
    ([xshift=\pv{a},yshift=\pv{a}]F.north east) -- (F.north east);
 \path[left color=fcol,right color=white,shading angle=-90]
 (F.north west) -- ++ (-\pv{a},\pv{a}) -- 
    ([xshift=-\pv{a},yshift=-\pv{a}]F.south west) -- (F.south west);
 \path[left color=fcol,right color=gray!50!black,shading angle=0]
 (F.south west) -- ++ (-\pv{a},-\pv{a}) -- 
    ([xshift=\pv{a},yshift=-\pv{a}]F.south east) -- (F.south east);
 \path[left color=fcol,right color=gray!50!black,shading angle=90]
 (F.south east) -- ++ (\pv{a},-\pv{a}) -- 
    ([xshift=\pv{a},yshift=\pv{a}]F.north east) -- (F.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\FFcolorbox[Fcol=mygreen]{Fe}\quad\FFcolorbox{C}\quad\FFcolorbox{P}\quad\FFcolorbox{O}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is straightforward to make this a `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{203,222,158}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{144,206,244}
\tcbset{Fcol/.code={\colorlet{fcol}{#1}}}
\newtcbox{\Embossed}[1][]{enhanced,Fcol=myblue,sharp corners,
width=2em-2pt,height=2em-0.5ex-1pt,boxrule=0pt,left=1pt,right=1pt,top=0.7ex,bottom=1pt,
on line,#1,colback=fcol,
    frame code={
    \path[left color=fcol,right color=white,shading angle=180]
 (frame.north west) -- ++ (-0.5ex,0.5ex) -- 
    ([xshift=0.5ex,yshift=0.5ex]frame.north east) -- (frame.north east);
 \path[left color=fcol,right color=white,shading angle=-90]
 (frame.north west) -- ++ (-0.5ex,0.5ex) -- 
    ([xshift=-0.5ex,yshift=-0.5ex]frame.south west) -- (frame.south west);
 \path[left color=fcol,right color=gray!50!black,shading angle=0]
 (frame.south west) -- ++ (-0.5ex,-0.5ex) -- 
    ([xshift=0.5ex,yshift=-0.5ex]frame.south east) -- (frame.south east);
 \path[left color=fcol,right color=gray!50!black,shading angle=90]
 (frame.south east) -- ++ (0.5ex,-0.5ex) -- 
    ([xshift=0.5ex,yshift=0.5ex]frame.north east) -- (frame.north east); 
    },
    }

\begin{document}
\Embossed[Fcol=mygreen]{Fe}\quad\Embossed{C}\quad\Embossed{P}\quad\Embossed{O}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is excellent. Thanks my dear